# Take difference between two vectors

Tags: r

I have two vectors:

```
a<-1:100
b<-sample(1:100,80)
```

I would like to display those elements of a that are not included in b.

I have tried `subset(a,a!==b)` and `a[a!==b]` but these didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `==` is for logical comparison, `!=` is for the negation... notice the single `=` in the second.

Comment: The string "didn't work" is not a built-in error message in R.

Comment: See `setdiff` perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of vectorization in R, using `==` wouldn't really work for your example. What you should use is `setdiff` or `is.element` (the latter of which is equivalent to `%in%`).

```
set.seed(1)
a<-1:100
b<-sample(1:100,80)
a[!is.element(a, b)]
#  [1]   8  15  33  48  52  54  56  66  68  72  74  80  90  91  92  93  94  96  98 100
setdiff(a, b)
#  [1]   8  15  33  48  52  54  56  66  68  72  74  80  90  91  92  93  94  96  98 100
```

If you look at how `==` works when you are comparing two vectors, it compares these one pair at a time, and recycles shorter vectors whenever necessary. In the first example of `x == y`, it seemed to work correctly, but look on to the second example, `x == z`. This basically checked to see whether `x[1] == z[1]`, `x[2] == z[2]`, and so on, so immediately, there was a misalignment of the sets.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:5
z <- c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)
x == y 
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x == z
#  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
x %in% z
#  [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

In R lingo, `%in%` is very common for identifying the common elements, and then negating that with `!`, but I find `setdiff` to be (at least more linguistically) logical.

Comment: How do `setdiff` and `%in%` compare in speed?

Comment: @Manetheran, really? If you're speaking from a purely quantitative perspective, and you're really good at detecting microseconds of difference, I would *guess* (purely by looking at the code for `setdiff` and `%in%`) that `setdiff` would be a bit slower because it includes conversion of the input using `as.vector` and it includes an `if ... else` condition.

Comment: @Manetheran, also note that `setdiff` and `%in%` are not the same. Again, looking at the code, you'll see that `setdiff` returns the `unique` results (which, again, might make it marginally slower than `%in%`).

Answer (score 1):

A useful command is `%in%`. This will return TRUE or FALSE, for every element of a vector a, whether that element is in vector b. You can then negate this using `!`. So:

```
a[!(a %in% b)]
```